# For non-negative definite symmetric matrices, $\mathrm{tr}(AB)\le \mathrm{tr}(A)\mathrm{tr}(B)$

Tags: matrices, trace, positive-semidefinite, transpose, matrix-norms

$\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{\mathrm{tr}}$
Is the inequality in title true for non-negative definite matrices?? I could neither prove this result, nor provide a counter example.

**Context**

I was trying to prove that Frobenius norm is a matrix norm, i.e.
$$||AB||_F\le||A||_F\cdot||B||_F\\
\iff\tr(B^\top A^\top AB)\le\tr(A^\top A)\cdot\tr(B^\top B)\\
\iff\tr(A^\top ABB^\top)\le\tr(A^\top A)\cdot\tr(B B^\top)$$
Now if that happens for all positive definite matrices $A$ and $B$, that means trace of product of two non-negative definite matrices is less than or equal to the product of their traces.

Please help, and provide a proof of this result which doesn't rely on the multiplicative inequality for Frobenius norm (since that result is proved to be equivalent to it, and I don't know the proof of that result).

Comment: @DietrichBurde, no, it doesn't answer this question. It is using the inequality of Frobenius norms, which is equivalent to this result and I don't know proof of.

Comment: I see. But it definitely answers your question "Is the inequality in title true for non-negative definite matrices?? I could neither prove this result, nor provide a counter example". Look up the proof for Frobenius norm inequality.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, and therefore, I need a proof of this result which doesn't rely on a result which I proved to be equivalent to it.

Comment: Then start searching here. I found [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3538652/frobenius-norm-and-operator-norm-inequality). Did you search already?

Comment: @DietrichBurde, Thank You very much, it answers the question. (I did search already, but used 'product of trace' and 'trace of product', didn't use the Frobenius norm terminology.)

Comment: No problem. It is not always clear how to find it. Most of the standard results can be found, however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $(e_j)$ be an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors of $B$ and let $(\lambda_j)$ denote the corresponding eigenvalues. Then
$$
\mathrm{tr}(AB)=\sum_j\langle AB e_j,e_j\rangle=\sum_j \lambda_j \langle A e_j, e_j\rangle\leq \max_j \lambda_j \mathrm{tr}(A)\leq \mathrm{tr}(A)\mathrm{tr}(B).
$$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Seems like this inequality can be further tightened as $trace(AB)\le \Vert B\Vert_2 tr(A)$, right?

Comment: If by $\lVert \cdot\rVert_2$ you mean the operator norm induced by the Euclidean norm, then yes.