# Proof that the square root of eigenvalues summation is less than the max egenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to proof the following inequality ([source, equation 17](https://www.mit.edu/%7Edimitrib/PTseng/papers/tnr_mtl.pdf)):

[image]

where $C \in R^{n\times n}$. I tried the following:

$$||C (\Lambda - \Lambda^T)||_F \le ||C||_F ||\Lambda - \Lambda^T ||
= \sqrt{\sum \lambda_i(C)} || \Lambda - \Lambda^T||_F$$

But I don't understand how to pursue farther. How to prove that the square root of the eigenvalues summation is less than the max eigenvalue?

Comment: is $C$ normal?  If not the statement is false -- e.g. select any non-zero nilpotent $C$.  On the other hand, if $C$ *is* normal, there are proofs here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3538652/frobenius-norm-and-operator-norm-inequality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $C$ in the paper is in the form of $(A^TA)^{-1}$ (eq. 7). So, it is positive definite and by a change of orthonormal basis, we may assume that $C$ is a nonnegative diagonal matrix. The inequality in question is now straightforward if you directly expand both sides entrywise. Alternatively, for any matrix $X=\pmatrix{x_1&x_2&\ldots&x_m}$, we have
$$
\|CX\|_F^2=\sum_j\|Cx_j\|_2^2\le\sum_j\|C\|_2^2\|x_j\|_2^2=\lambda_\max(C)^2\|X\|_F^2.
$$
Since $C$ is positive definite, if we take square roots on both sides, the result follows.

Comment: didn't get why $||C||_2^2 = \lambda_{max}(C)^2$. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @randomndrandom $C$ is positive definite. Therefore its largest eigenvalue is equal to its largest singular value.

Comment: No problem with that. I meant $||C||_2^2 = \sum \lambda_i(C)$ how did it end up equals to the max eigenvalue?

Comment: @randomndrandom You seem to have misunderstood the meaning of $\|C\|_2$. It is the standard notation for the *induced* 2-norm of $C$, i.e. the largest singular value of $C$.